# Clarification: confidence interval of the (slope of the) regression line

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, terminology, definition

When confidence intervals are referenced in the regression context, I often see them mentioned (generally speaking) as "of the slope of the regression line," or as "of the regression line."

Is there a meaningful difference between these two descriptions? The latter seems more precise, as it accounts for uncertainty with the intercept. But if applied to the same regression analysis, are they both referring to the same thing?

Comment: In a simple regression with one regressor (X), since there is an intercept (alpha), and a slope coefficient (beta) on X, it is better to be precise and state which CI. There are three possible (for alpha, beta, or alpha+beta.X), although usually it is the beta CI that is of most interest.

Comment: With simple regression - the regression line is $y = \alpha + \beta x$. So if you are referring to the confidence on the slope parameter, $\beta$, I would say it's technically more correct to say "the confidence on the slope". If you are referring to the location of the line as a whole, i.e. both slope and vertical displacement = intercept, then "the regression line" is more appropriate... although I have never seen this before.